# How to change the horizontal axis color of a Column Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have got a Google [Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) and I would like to change the color of its horizontal axis.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/chM9A/

```
function drawGenderColumnChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Age', 'Female', 'Male'],
        ['13-17', 500, 600],
        ['18-24', 700, 800],
        ['25-34', 960, 950],
        ['35-44', 1030, 1100],
        ['44-54', 1030, 900],
        ['55-64', 950, 800],
        ['65+', 700, 500], ]);

    var options = {
        colors: ['#ADD6EA', '#DFB9D1'],
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        },
        bar: {
            groupWidth: "94%"
        },
        axisFontSize: 0,
        vAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('age_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I have been dissecting the documentation and it doesn't look like the API would let us do that. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `baselineColor`:

```
vAxis: {
            baselineColor:'Red',
            textPosition: 'none',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B4AfE/1/

Comment: Oh... thanks. I actually tried `baselineColor` but on the horizontal axis. Do you have any idea why this must be applied to `vAxis` instead of `hAxis` (which would be more logical)?

Comment: Although all lines (base+gridlines) for the vAxis are horizontal lines, they belong to the vertical axis(and vice-versa) . So the baseline for the vAxis is a horizontal line that marks the 0-value for the vAxis